# two AVPlayers, how to know which one finished playing

Tags: swift, avplayer

If I have one AVPlayer, I could monitor the `AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime`. But if I have two AVPlayers, I wouldn't know which one finished. Is there a way to know which finishes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try

```
@objc func playerDidFinishPlaying( _ sender: Notification) {
   if let _ = sender.object as? Player1 {
   }
}
```

---

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(playerDidFinishPlaying(_:)) , name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: nil)
```

Comment: Thank you! I think it would be `player1.currentItem`